# How to make checkboxes checked based on the set value in the database?

Tags: php

I'm trying to set the checkboxes checked based on the values for the record in my database. Below is the $categories array which lists all of the different options and $book_categories is the array for the values for the specific record retrieved from the database. So as you see below, from $book_categories this specific record only has category 2 listed therefore only the second checkbox (English) should be selected. What do I need to modify in the HTML to make this happen?

```
$categories = array('0' => array('categoryid' => 1, 'name' => 'Technology'), '1' => array('categoryid' => 2, 'name' => 'English'), '2' => array('categoryid' => 3, 'name' => 'Science'));

$book_categories = array('2' => 2);

    <!-- HTML -->
<label>Category:</label>
<?php foreach($categories as $category) : ?>
    <input class="radio" type="checkbox" name="book-category[]" value="<?php echo $category['categoryid'] ?> " /><span class="radio-label"><?php echo $category['name'] ?></span><br />
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This is what I tried but it's not working:

```
<?php foreach($categories as $category) : ?>
                <input class="radio" type="checkbox" name="book-category[]" value="<?php echo $category['categoryid'] ?> " <?php in_array($category['categoryid'], $book_categories)?'checked':'' ?> /><span class="radio-label"><?php echo $category['name'] ?></span><br />
            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table is like that:

```
<?php
        $categories = [
            '0' => [
                'categoryid' => 1,
                'name' => 'Technology'
            ],
            '1' => [
                'categoryid' => 2,
                'name' => 'English'
            ],
            '2' => [
                'categoryid' => 3,
                'name' => 'Science'
            ]];
?>
```

so when iterating on it, if you want to check your check box, you have to add checked attribut to you input radio:

```
<input class="radio" type="checkbox" name="book-category[]" <?php if ($category['categoryid'] === 2){echo checked} ?> " />
<span class="radio-label"><?php echo $category['name'] ?></span>
<br/>
```

you can replace 2 by $book_categories[2]

or you you can have multiple category, use in_array in the condition:

```
<?php if (in_array($category['categoryid'], $book_categories){echo checked} ?>
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error when I add the code in the input tag Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO)

Comment: try with <?php if ($category['categoryid'] === 2){print('checked');} ?>

Comment: I was missing a ). Thanks so much!